# Android C2DM - Works in real device but not in Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, android-c2dm

I'm trying to use the C2DM framework.

I can receive push messages on my real device (so it seems that my application code is fine) but with the same application I don't receive any messages on the emulator (I tried with the Google API 8, Google API 10 and Google API 15).

Retrieving a registration id for the device is fine.

I just don't receive any messages

Do you know what could be wrong?

Thank you for your help and regards,

Answer (score 2):

Since emulators (by default) dont have Google Account service (Gmail/Market) available, thats why you cant test on them - unless you configure your google account. Otherwise, it should be tested on real devices

Comment: if he managed to install Market to the emulator and log in using a Gmail account, then C2DM should work on the emulator too . API >=8

Comment: I already log in using a Gmail account on the emulator but I didn't manage to install Market. Thank you all for your responses

Comment: what do you mean **"manage to install Market"**? does it give any error when you install?

Comment: no, I tried various tutorials and I have no error but the Market wasn't finally installed...

Comment: try downloading and installing this one http://hotfile.com/dl/141531271/f5ee4e0/AndroidMarket_v3.4.4.apk.html

Comment: Thank you Waqas. When typing adb -e install AndroidMarket_v3.4.4.apk I have a INSTALL_FAILURE_ALREADY_EXISTS. But actually I don't have the Market displayed on the apps... And receiving the C2DM still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

of course it will not work emulator . coz C2DM is configure with Gmail account for mapping a unique device .

C2DM get API generate the **device id vai gmail account and that id is unique** and emulator dont have gmail API to configure account

Answer (score 1):

-You must have android sdk 2.2+ and google service must be running on your emulator (We would recommend to install google sdk 2.3.1)

-You must register your Google account on your emulator. You can do it by going to Settings -> Accounts & Sync and add gmail account. You cannot receive push notification unless Google account is set.

-You must register your developer’s email address for your application at google . Please note one thing that this account is developer’s account and might not be account which is configured in ‘Accounts & Sync’ settings.